# How to change Primefaces fileupload cancel button icon

Tags: primefaces

I want to use jQuery `ui-icon-close` instead of `ui-icon-cancel`. So I go to the `fileupload.js` file in the primefaces jar (3.3.1), change the reference to `ui-icon-cancel` to `ui-icon-close` (line#2082, upload template). But it doesn't work. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Did you verify that your changes made it to your browser? What does "not work" mean?

Comment: Yes. I have checked the deployed jar and the change is there. But the cancel button icon remain ui-icon-cancel but not ui-icon-close. Besides changing it directly in the original jar, I also downloaded the src code and changed it there then generated a new jar. It's not working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easier way to solve this problem:

1. I added an id to my fileupload control:

   ```
   <p:fileUpload id="related_file" ..../>
   ```
2. Then in my css, I add the following lines:

   ```
   div[id*=related_file] .ui-icon-cancel{
       background-position: -96px -128px !important;
   }
   ```

This works and the cancel button ends up using the ui-icon-closeThick icon.

But I would still like to know why my original approach didn't work if anybody knows the answer. Thanks.