# Remove plus icon on Choose button in <p:fileUpload> primefaces component

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

Is there a way to remove plus icon on Choose button in  primefaces component.

Comment: You can use this [EXAMPLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594499/how-to-change-primefaces-fileupload-cancel-button-icon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if still no luck. You can put this css code (tested) to remove icon:

```
 .fileupload-buttonbar .fileinput-button .ui-icon-plusthick{
         display: none !important;
 }
```

And this code to move Choose more left:

```
 .fileupload-buttonbar .fileinput-button  .ui-button-text{
     padding-left: 1em!important;
 }
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you it works. But how were able to figure out which class to override I have looked in the firebug the classes associated to this icon are ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-plusthick.

Answer (score 3):

I tried @Darka's approach but it failed with Primefaces 3.5.10.

This worked for me.

```
     .ui-fileupload-choose .ui-icon {
         visibility: hidden !important;
     }
     .ui-fileupload-upload .ui-icon {
         visibility: hidden !important;
     }
     .ui-fileupload-cancel .ui-icon {
         visibility: hidden !important;
     }
```

I hope it helps also.

Answer (score 0):

In Primefaces 5.3 use:

```
span.ui-fileupload-choose > span.ui-icon-plusthick{
    display: none !important;
}
span.ui-fileupload-choose > span.ui-button-text{
    padding-left: 1em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Primefaces 6.1 use:

```
.ui-fileupload-simple .ui-icon-plusthick {
    display: none !important;
}

.ui-fileupload-simple .ui-button-text{
    padding-left: 1em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For file upload in advanced mode (tested on PrimeFaces 6+):

```
.ui-fileupload .ui-icon-plusthick {
  display: none !important;
}

.ui-fileupload .ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-n {
  display: none !important;
}

.ui-fileupload .ui-icon-cancel {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the file primeicons.css has all the icons classes.
Overwrite the property *content* value with the respective chosen icon code.

For example, if you want to replace the icon for the papper-clip:

```
/* \e97b is the papper-clip code found in primeicons.css */
    .pi-plus:before {
        content: "\e97b"; 
      }
```